# Python logger not working when I run package through __main__.py

Tags: python, python-import, python-logging

I have a python package that I use for data preprocessing which I usually run through a Makefile. I want to run it like so: `python3 -m utils.features`, so that's why I created `__main__.py`. However, if I run it like this (instead of `python3 -m utils.features.build_features`) all the loggers stop producing output, both defined in this file and from other modules imported in `build_features.py`. Why does this happen?

My project structure:

```
utils/
├─ features/
│  ├─ __init__.py
│  ├─ __main__.py
│  ├─ build_features.py
```

`__init__.py`:

`__main__.py`:

```py
from .build_features import build_features

build_features()
```

`build_features.py`:

```py
imports...

def build_features():
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.info("Reading data")
    ...

    logger.info("Building features")
    ...

    logger.info("Saving data")
    ...


if __name__ == "__main__":
    log_fmt = "%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format=log_fmt)

    # find .env automagically by walking up directories until it's found, then
    # load up the .env entries as environment variables
    load_dotenv(find_dotenv())

    build_features()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you setup your loggers in the `if __name__ == "__main__"` of `build_features.py`.

Move the logger setup to `__main__.py` and it'll work.